# KendoGrid MVC - Hide column in the Detail grid with parent data.columnX value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, show-hide, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this column in the detail or hierarchical kendogrid and want to hide the column based on the data.columnX value coming from the parent.

```
    .Columns(columns =>
      {  
       columns.Bound(v => v.UpdateBy).Title("Edited By").Width("10%").Hidden("#= Data.OperationType # == 4 ? true : false");
      }

or even this is also not working

    .Columns(columns =>
      {  
       columns.Bound(v => v.UpdateBy).Title("Edited By").Width("10%").Hidden("#=Data.HideUserCol#");
      }
```

But this is not working for me, i guess i am making a small mistake here in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden could be either **false** or **true** if I am not mistaken.

What you are trying to achieve cannot be configured on the server (through the MVC wrappers).

You need to use the [detailInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit) event that is triggered and hide the column manually with the [hideColumn](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-hideColumn) method.

Comment: I finally performed the action with the help of DetailExpand event.                              function detailExpandEvt(e) {
            var mRow = e.masterRow;            
            var hideRevert = this.dataItem(mRow).HideRevert;
            
            if (hideRevert){
                var pgID = this.dataItem(mRow).PartnerGroupID;
                var childgrid = $("#HistoryGrid_" +pgID).data("kendoGrid");
                childgrid.hideColumn(10);
            }        
        }